# Exception SpecFlow.Plus.Shared.Services.Activation.ActivationException

Tags: testing, exception, automation, specflow

When running/debugging SpecFlow tests for the first time, you might encountered this exception in Output > Test in Visual Studio.

```
Exception thrown: 'SpecFlow.Plus.Shared.Services.Activation.ActivationException'
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to Visual Studio Output > Test
2. Copy the link to login and activate and re-run the test

Example:
https://account.specflow.org/clientactivation/welcome/Runner/-some-hash-here/NotActivatedYet